# How to add elements in listview on button click

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add elements in listview on button click and typed element on top of the listview. but all elements gets repeated except last. i did this-->

```
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT);
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lview);


    final ArrayList<String> todoitem = new ArrayList<>();
    final  ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa= new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoitem);

    lv.setAdapter(aa);

}

EditText et;
ListView lv;

public void onBtnClick(View v){

    int k= lv.getCount();
    String a1[]= new String[k+1];
    for (int i=k-1;i>=0;i--){

        for (int j=k; j>0; j--) {
            a1[j] = lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }
        a1[0] = et.getText().toString();
        ArrayAdapter<String> aan = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a1);
        lv.setAdapter(aan);
        et.setText("");

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding your code, but I think this is really what you are after:

```
public void onBtnClick(View v){

    int k= lv.getCount();
    String a1[]= new String[k+1];
    a1[0] = et.getText().toString();
    et.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        a1[i + 1] = lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> aan = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, a1);
    lv.setAdapter(aan);
}
```